# Access Hard Disk drive hooked on router remotelly

Tags: router, dynamic-dns

I have a created a DynDNS domain in bounceme.com. I have connected the hard disk on my router via usb, the domain in bounceme.com goes to the router interface.
But I have no idea how I can access the hard disk folders remotelly. Do I need to open some specific ports? The Hard Disk is a 4TB seagate

I can access the contents of the Hard Disk using this address:

> file://mydomain.bounceme.net/usbdisk/

But its public (no password protected) and I can only read the files nothing more

[image: Router config page]

Comment: What's the router make/model?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart its Inteno DG301AL

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would Setup a port forward for port 139 pointing to the routers lan address. (Usually 192.168.1.1)

Because the firmware running in your router will not let you forward traffic to it's internal service running the drive share. this will not be possible at the router level.

You can either:

1. upgrade your router to one that supports running a VPN & file share at the router level.
2. Run a openvpn server or similar VPN platform behind the router on the local lan. Allowing access to the drive share through encrypted tunnel.
3. Get on the openwrt forums and ask if there are plans to support your router model in future revisions.

Hope this helps.

https://serverfault.com/questions/36100/port-forwarding-for-samba

Comment: I cannot set the Destination to 192.168.1.1 I get the message that I cannot use the GW IP

Comment: How about "127.0.0.1" ?

Comment: "IP is not in the same network as the gateway 192.168.1.1"

Comment: Interesting, that router comes with a version of openwrt on it right? I'm kinda shocked it's not easier to do what you are trying to do. You may have to bypass the GUI to modify how this is setup by default. https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/cifs.server

Comment: I uploaded a foto of the content sharing page. In the previous version of the firmware it was much easier to fix that as you can see here : http://screenshots.portforward.com/routers/Inteno/DG301AL/Content_Sharing_Configure.htm

Comment: Did you try the ftp option?

Comment: I tried to open a ftp port but again I dont know the address where I should point it.... can you guide me?

Comment: Because any service you run on the router will be on one of the router interface ports. It looks like they are only available on the lan. Giving you no choice but to port forward from the wan to the routers internal address.

Comment: Another option would be to run a VPN to connect to your lan, and then bypass the firewall issue your having

Comment: I can run a VPN on the router?

Comment: It doesn't look like that router supports a VPN running on it. And oddly even though it's running a manufacturer version of openwrt. I didn't find it on the compatibility list for a regular version of openwrt that would support an openvpn dameon. With out support for this, you would have to run openvpn on another device and port forward to that, giving you access to the share via internet.

Comment: I updated your answer. Sorry I could not help you further